# JavaFX 11-13: How to render pixels without Screen HiDpi Scaling?

Tags: image, javafx, blurry, highdpi

How can I avoid all up/down scalings of an image? All variants I checked result in some scalings due to the windows screen scaling informations.

**Motivation**
I have some renderers, that create images out of documents (svg, pdf, etc.) in a size. These images become blurry, when they are upscaled by JavaFX. I did not find a way to get rid of it.

- In Swing the solution would be to use a AbstractMultiResolutionImage. But that does not work for JavaFX.
- I cannot use the ImageLoader, as I have multi-page documents
- The x2 filename suffix tweak that was introduced for retina display does not work as I do not have filenames and the scale factors may be different from 100% and 200%

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is what you meant but you could try using the @2x mechanism of JavaFX. Basically this will allow you to provide images in different resolutions, so that they do not have to be upscaled. If you provide two images, say `myicon.png` and `myicon@2x.png` and access it via its basename `myicon.png`, then JavaFX will automatically pick the one with the best resolution for your screen.
https://dlsc.com/2017/08/29/javafx-tip-27-hires-retina-icons/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this is designed for macos, as there is a 200% scale factor. In windows, you have a greater viarity of steps (e.g. 125%).
Also, this would only work for prerendered files that are accessed by a file name. 

In my case, I have a rendering algorithm that creates images on the fly.